# How can i force UIViewControllers to load with my custom UIWindows frame size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Because my App makes use of hardware the simulators just don't do it. (no Bluetooth, no proper GPS)

My layouts adapt to the resolution, but as we all know, an iPad has less width as an iPhone. I have an iPad mini 2 here to test the App but i would like to enforce the resolution to an iPhone6 equivalent.

I can try to set the UIWindow to (576, 1024) but every UIViewController loads with a self.view.frame of the original resolution.

It is way too much work to go into every ViewController and manually give it a different frame, thats why i would like to force the App into a UIWindow.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 576, 1024)];

// ViewController will have a frame of (0, 0, 768, 1024)
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = myVC;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

**EDIT**

basically i want to mock a different screen size from the beginning (start) of the app. I don't mind black bars on the (real) screen as it is only to test/debug/confirm layouts on different aspect ratios.

Comment: why are you changing the window frame ? Window frame can't be changed.Instead change the fames of views in view controllers.

Comment: the idea is to change at ONE spot, for testing and not 1000 views in 20 viewcontrollers